# TextView's text is not changing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, textview, layout-inflater

ProgressDialog is depracted thats why I create a layout and put a progressbar and a textview and put this layout into a dialog. Until now, everything works well but in runtime I cannot change the textview's text.

Here is my code (in OnCreate Method was called)

```
View progressLayout = LayoutInflater.FromContext(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.progressbar,null);
var txtMessage  = progressLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.loading_msg);
txtMessage.Text = "My message is this";          
txtMessage.SetText("my tesst", TextView.BufferType.Normal);
progressLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.loading_msg)
.SetText("hobaa",TextView.BufferType.Normal);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);           
builder.SetView(Resource.Layout.progressbar);

Dialog dialog = builder.Create();
dialog.SetTitle("My Title");            
dialog.SetCancelable(false);            
dialog.Show();
```

and my progress.axml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="13dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loader"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
      />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/loading_msg"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/loader"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The only reason `ProgressDialog` is deprecated is because Google doesn't think you should be showing a UI-blocking, non-cancelable dialog while you're doing work. If you're just going to replicate the same behavior, you might as well just use `ProgressDialog`.

Comment: @MikeM. I see Mike and its a good argument. But my colleuge needs that kind of control, thats why I am doing this. Is there better way to do? I'll create a wrapper that timeout will be able to settable to dismiss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
builder.SetView(Resource.Layout.progressbar);
```

to

```
builder.SetView(progressLayout);
```